# Image is not saving on mobile device after taking picture with camera package

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to save an image to my local mobile device when I use this code from the pub.dev example page of the camera package. However I am not finding the file saved on the device. Can anyone please help me with how to save the image taken to a given path

```
void onTakePictureButtonPressed() {
    takePicture().then((XFile? file) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          imageFile = file;
          videoController?.dispose();
          videoController = null;
        });
        if (file != null) {
          showInSnackBar('Picture saved to ${file.path}');
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Could you share the name of the package you are using?

Comment: i am using camera: ^0.10.0

Comment: The snackBar shows you the path of the file? Is the snackBar showed?

Comment: yes I get the message when I run the app that it is saved but I do not find the file anywhere on my mobile device. Any idea why not?

Answer (score 1):

Using await ImagePicker.pickImage(...), you are already on the right track because the function returns a File.

The File class has a copy method, which you can use to copy the file (which is already saved on disk by either the camera or by lying in gallery) and put it into your application documents directory:

```
// using your method of getting an image
final File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: imageSource);

// getting a directory path for saving
final String path = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().path;

// copy the file to a new path
final File newImage = await image.copy('$path/image1.png');

setState(() {
  _image = newImage;
});
```

You should also note that you can get the path of the image file from `ImagePicker` using `image.path`, which will also contain the file ending that you might want to extract and you can save your image path by using `newImage.path`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use path provider and save the images like this

https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider

```dart
final XFile? image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
if (image == null) return;
final String newFile = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().path;
final var fileName = basename(file.path);
final File localImage = await image.saveTo('$newFile/$fileName');
```